# Why did Arjuna not have any issues fighting with the Kurus in VirAta battle?

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna, kurukshetra

In the [virAta parva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virata_Parva) of MahAbhArata. There was a great battle of Virata where Arjuna defeated the whole of Kuru army single handedly.

If he did not have any guilt, fear, sorrow in fighting with his own people in Virata then why he had such issues only during the final Kurukshetra battle?

Comment: In Virat war, Arjuna only had to defeat the Kuru warriors. However in Kurukshetra he had to kill them. He did not want to kill Bhishma or Drona and hence refused to fight.